# Blazor client hosted constructor dependency injection in server controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I am getting an HTTP 500 when performing an API request within a Blazor client-hosted application. The request is successful if I omit the controller parameters, however, once I set a parameter inside the controller I get an HTTP 500.

I have checked and tested the container and the interfaces are registered. The client works as long as I don't supply parameters inside the server controller constructor.

**What do I need to do to have contructor injection inside the server controllers within a blazor application?**

*At the time of writing, I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.2 preview 4 & .NET Core 3 preview.*

---

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public Startup()
    {
        _dependency = new Dependency();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        _dependency
            .SetServiceCollection(services)
            .SetServiceProvider(services.BuildServiceProvider());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBlazorDebugging();
        }

        app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<Client.Startup>();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
        });

        _dependency
            .SetWebHostEnvironment(env)
            .ConfigureDependencies()
            .ConfigureDatabases();
    }
}
```

**Dependency.cs**

```
public class Dependency : IDependency
{
    private IServiceCollection _services;
    private IServiceProvider _provider;
    private IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public IDependency SetServiceCollection(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (_services != null)
            throw new AlreadyConfiguredException($"{nameof(services)} is already configured.");

        _services = services;
        return this;
    }

    public IDependency SetServiceProvider(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        if (_provider != null)
            throw new AlreadyConfiguredException($"{nameof(provider)} is already configured.");

        _provider = provider;
        return this;
    }

    public IDependency SetWebHostEnvironment(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        if (_environment != null)
            throw new AlreadyConfiguredException($"{nameof(environment)} is already configured.");

        _environment = environment;
        return this;
    }

    public IDependency ConfigureDatabases()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(_environment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{_environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var config = builder.Build();
        var database = config.GetConnectionString("MenuDatabase");

        MenuStartup.Configure(_services, database);
        OpeningTimeStartup.Configure(_services, database);

        return this;
    }

    public IDependency ConfigureDependencies()
    {
        // Bounded Contexts

        // Domain Models
        _services.AddTransient<IMenu, Menu.Menu>();

        // Infrastructure
        _services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(Repository<,>));
        _services.AddTransient<IFactory, Factory>();
        _services.AddSingleton<ICompositeCache, MemoryCompositeCache>();
        _services.AddTransient<IDataContextFactory, DataContextFactory>();
        _services.AddTransient<IMenuRepository, MenuRepository>();

        return this;
    }
}
```

**IDependency.cs**

```
public interface IDependency
{
    IDependency SetServiceCollection(IServiceCollection services);
    IDependency SetServiceProvider(IServiceProvider buildServiceProvider);
    IDependency ConfigureDependencies();
    IDependency SetWebHostEnvironment(IWebHostEnvironment environment);
    IDependency ConfigureDatabases();
}
```

**MenuDataController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MenuDataController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMenu _menu;

    public MenuDataController(IMenu menu)
    {
        _menu = menu;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<SpiceViewModel> Spices()
    {
        return new Spice[] { };
    }
}
```

**Spices.razor**

```
@inject HttpClient Http

<div class="alert alert-secondary mt-4" role="alert">
    <span class="oi oi-pencil mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <strong>@Title</strong>

    <span class="text-nowrap">
        Please take our
        <a target="_blank" class="font-weight-bold" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2093904">brief survey</a>
    </span>
    and tell us what you think.

    @if (spices == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spicesSelect">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="spicesSelect">
                <option>None</option>
                @foreach (var spice in spices)
                {
                    <option value="@spice.Id">@spice.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] string Title { get; set; }

    SpiceViewModel[] spices;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        spices = await Http.GetJsonAsync<SpiceViewModel[]>("api/MenuData/Spices");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I thought it would be simple enough to understand if you have written a client-hosted Blazor app. If I try to inject into the SampleDataController it blows up.

Comment: Show the code please...

Comment: Please supply the requested code - we cannot see your screen and cannot see what parameters you are supplying or how you are calling the API. This is all relevant information to helping you.

Comment: I have added the code. This is the basic framework of a Blazor client-hosted app. I have activated **IMenu** as a test using the IServiceProvider from the IServicesCollection.

Comment: `AddTransient<IMenu, Menu.Menu>()` looks strange and you didn't include the related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my eyes by wearing my glasses and it turns out there are multiple constructors in the Controller. Turning on server logging as recommended by Microsoft helped quite a lot.

- The example I showed microsoft had multiple constructors with a single parameter. The DI does not know which to choose.
- The DI is not activating automatically instance types that are not registered in the container.

Comment: So the solution was your upgrading your eyesight, right ? But hey, what was the problem ? Can you share, please...

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who searched "blazor controller dependency injection" and found this question, here's what I got.

The original Blazor client-hosted project template shows you the following code (WeatherForecastController.cs) once you completed the new project creatoin.

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}
```

In order to use the db context that you created on your own (or any other Dependency Injection), you just need to modify the original constructor instead of creating a new one (keep one and only one constructor).

```
public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, MyDbContext context)
{
    this._context = context;
    this.logger = logger;
}
```